# show remaining content - DIV with overflow: hidden

Tags: javascript, html, overflow

how can I show hidden content of div with overflow: hidden using JavaScript ? Example: to scroll down programatically ?

Comment: Need more clarification. When would you show it? After a certain interval has passed, in reaction to some other event, in reaction to the user performing some action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using `.scrollTop`.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/RUhpC/